# Combine results from different procedures into a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**What I wanted:** I want to execute a procedure for each distinct entry in the table and display all the result in a single table.

**What I did:**

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)=''
Select @sql = @sql + ' exec proc1 ' + Convert(nvarchar(50),s1.product) + ';'
      from  (select distinct(s2.product) as product from sales s2) as s1;
exec (@sql)
```

**What the problem is:** it returns me n number of tables, n being number of distinct entries in the table. How do I union all of them?

Comment: could you screenshot and show the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Thank you everyone.

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)='Declare @tempTable Table (product nvarchar(50) ); '
Select @sql = @sql + 'Insert into @tempTable exec proc1 ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),s1.product) + ';'
 from (Select Distinct(s2.product) as product from Sales s2) as s1;
Set @sql = @sql + 'Select * from @tempTable';
Exec (@sql)
```